# Avoiding newline in latex report

Tags: spacing, line-breaking

I am writing one auto report in which I need to have some breakline and vertical spacing. I use newline but sometimes it is in horizontal mode. So I have to use `\leavevmode` before it.

```
 \leavevmode
 \newline
```

Sometimes I get error message with `\leavevmode` also. I am sick of fixing errors so I am planning to replace newline with it's equivalent alternative. can you please suggest what can I use?

Comment: If you want to "leave a blank line" in the output, hit return twice, type `\bigskip`, hit return twice and continue with the text.